# Iteratively testing for an input that is numeric in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, isnumeric, isalpha

I have to test if user's input is numeric. Otherwise, I need to ask for input again. It sounds simple, right? But, check the following function

```
# Request number from user
def request_number():
    number = input("Please, enter the card number you want to check: ")
    if number.isnumeric():
        return int(number)
    elif number.isalpha() or number.isalnum() or number.isdecimal():
        request_number()
```

It Works fine if the first input from the user is actually a number `4111111111111111`

But, if the user inputs first a string, such as `asbsdl`. The function correctly asks a second time for a number, but even when you enter a number, it returns `None`.

Can anybody shed some light? Thanks.

Comment: You ignore the recursive call return value. See the duplicate.

Comment: However, you really should not use recursion here, see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](//stackoverflow.com/q/23294658)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Was on this for quite some time...

Comment: ... or the whole set of `is...` checks... The duplicate has an answer which you can pretty much copy/paste to ask for input until it's a valid `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the reason is because you aren't returning your recursive call. To fix this, change the recursion call (last line) to `return request_number()`